# SQL query data between dates, efficiency

Tags: sql, oracle11g, crystal-reports

I'm trying to search through a fairly large (56m+ row) table using an SQL query. The complication to just being able to do some quick SQL query like this:

```
Select *COLUMNS*
From *Table*
Where *Conditions* And
      LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP between {StartDate} and {EndDate}
```

is that I need to pull the 23:00 - 24:00 hour from the day before {StartDate} without pulling the rest of the data from that date. {StartDate} and {EndDate} are user entered fields in a DATE format. LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP is a TIMESTAMP data type.

Is there a more time-efficient way of doing this than having to do something like:

```
TRUNC(CAST(LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP AS DATE), 'HH') BETWEEN {StartDate}-1/24 and {EndDate}+23/24
```

Data will look like:

```
ITEM   LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP
----   ----------------------------------
A      2/12/2018 10:02:19.214528 AM -0500
B      2/14/2018 11:02:19.224528 PM -0500
C      2/16/2018 01:02:19.412528 AM -0500
D      2/16/2018 11:02:19.412528 PM -0500
```

And if I search from {StartDate} = 2/15/2018 through {EndDate} = 2/16/2018, I want to capture B & C.

Comment: Does your current query find the data you expect, just slowly? And you said "in a DATE format" - what is the data type when the user-entered parameters are seen by the query? Are they strings (in what format?) or actual dates (with or without non-midnight times)? Also, do you really want 23:00:00 to 00:00:00, or up to 23:59:59.999...? Some sample data, parameters and expected result might be useful.

Comment: @Alex
the
'TRUNC(CAST(LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP AS DATE), 'HH') BETWEEN {StartDate}-1/24 and {EndDate}-23/24'

Will pull data, but slowly.

'Where *Conditions* And'
' LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP between {StartDate} - 1/24 and {EndDate}'

won't pull any data.

I need data from 11pm the night before until 11pm tonight.

In the database it looks like ' 2/12/2018 10:02:19.214528 AM -0500' (TIMESTAMP with TIME ZONE)

Comment: Please edit your question to add information. I'd guess the values being passed in are either dates or timestamps without time zones and that's throwing the comparison, but without [an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's kind of hard to tell. Also the question is 11pm-midnight, your comment is saying a different range, please clarify that. (`{EndDate}-23/24` will give you 1am, not 11pm).

Comment: Original question edited, @AlexPoole

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest:

```
Where *Conditions* And
      LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP between {StartDate} - 1/24 and {EndDate}
```

Comment: I've tried this and it just ends up returning no data. I'm not sure if it's a type mismatch or what

Answer (score 0):

> I need data from 11pm the night before until 11pm tonight
>
> if I search from {StartDate} = 2/15/2018 through {EndDate} = 2/16/2018, I want to capture B & C.

Assuming `LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP` is indexed you can utilise that with:

```
Where *Conditions* And
  LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP >= {StartDate} -  1/24 and
  LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP <  {EndDate}   + 23/24
```

Again assuming that the variables are actually dates with time set to midnight, `{StartDate} - 1/24` gives you 23:00 on the day before that start date, and `{EndDate} + 23/24` gives you 23:00 on the end date.

With your sample data in a CTE and the filter dates as date literals:

```
with your_table (item, log_entry_timestamp) as (
            select 'A', to_timestamp_tz('2/12/2018 10:02:19.214528 AM -0500',
              'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM TZHTZM') from dual
  union all select 'B', to_timestamp_tz('2/14/2018 11:02:19.224528 PM -0500',
              'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM TZHTZM') from dual
  union all select 'C', to_timestamp_tz('2/16/2018 01:02:19.412528 AM -0500',
              'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM TZHTZM') from dual
  union all select 'D', to_timestamp_tz('2/16/2018 11:02:19.412528 PM -0500',
              'MM/DD/YYYY HH:MI:SS.FF6 AM TZHTZM') from dual
)
select *
from your_table
where LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP >= date '2018-02-15' -  1/24
  and LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP <  date '2018-02-16' + 23/24;

I LOG_ENTRY_TIMESTAMP              
- ---------------------------------
B 2018-02-14 23:02:19.224528 -05:00
C 2018-02-16 01:02:19.412528 -05:00
```

But you need to verify what the actual data types are for the values being used for the variables, and whether any time zone conversion is being done, which could affect the range of values you actually match.